# Closing windows by code QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, editing

I'm trying to close the window (by code) that appears right after the "add feature" tool is called. This is the window I'm talking about:

[image]

This is my plugin code:

```
    def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    self.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
    # CLOSE WINDOW CODE HERE
```

Everything I tried closed my QGIS program. Is what I'm asking possible?
If so, how?

Comment: Uncheck `Settings -> Options -> Supress attribute form pop-up after feature creation`.

Comment: Thank you. That worked :) I already had it unchecked but checking made it work. Do you know how to implement it on code so i can turn "ON" and "OFF" in the plugin?

Comment: Turning "ON": QSettings().setValue( '/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog', True )

Turning "OFF": QSettings().setValue( '/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog', False )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def run(self):
"""Run method that performs all the real work"""
self.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
QSettings().setValue(/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog', False)
```

Turning "ON":

QSettings().setValue(/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog', True )

Turning "OFF":

QSettings().setValue(/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog', False )