# In pyqgis, how to add a feature to a layer without opening any edit form?

Tags: pyqgis

I want to add a feature to a polygon vector layer in QGIS.

I have:

```
myLayer.featureAdded.connect(doSomething)
```

And when I click on a button:

```
iface.setActiveLayer(myLayer)
myLayer.startEditing()
iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
```

So when the button is clicked I can draw a polygon on the canvas. When I end the drawing the usual edit form appears.

Is there a way to prevent it from opening or to close it immediately? (I want to edit the attributes programmatically in doSomething).

Comment: See the comment section of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260002/closing-windows-by-code-qgis-2-18#comment411496_260002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deactivate the data entry form in the QGIS options. Not sure where to find this option in pyQGIS.

---

[image]

Comment: maybe like that :  
Turning "ON": `QSettings().setValue( '/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog', True )`     Turning "OFF": `QSettings().setValue( '/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog', False )`   thanks to @José-Gabriel

Comment: The configuration can be set for the layer only from pyqgis with myLayer.setFeatureFormSuppress(1)

Comment: @vwrobel Which is deprecated and not available in QGIS 3.x. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/doc/api_break.dox#L2572

Comment: For reference, using QGIS 3.x, you would need to do this: `form_config = layer.editFormConfig()` `form_config.setSuppress(QgsEditFormConfig.SuppressOn)` `layer.setEditFormConfig(form_config)`